# decoding hexed UTF-8 characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the following error code produced by Apache:

```
\xed\xe5 \xff\xb\xff\xe5\xf2\xf1\xff \xef\xf0\xe8\xeb\xee\xe6\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5\xec
```

I've found that the `\x` escape sequence states that the following two characters are UTF hex symbols. For example the word `HELLO` can be encoded as `\x48\x45\x4C\x4C\x4F`. But I can't seem to figure out how to decode the string that I have?
I've searched through UTF encoding tables but haven't found any characters that match the encoded symbols that I have. I don't even know should I be looking for one byte or 2 bytes encodings.

I'm on the PC that uses Russian locale, if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your string is cp-1251 encoded:

```
s.decode('string_escape').decode('cp1251')
```

prints some stuff that appears meaningful (except that `\xb` is incorrect - copypaste error?):

```
s = r'\xed\xe5 \xff?xb\xff\xe5\xf2\xf1\xff \xef\xf0\xe8\xeb\xee\xe6\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5\xec'

s = s.decode('string_escape').decode('cp1251')
#не я?xbяется приложением
```

> I don't even know should I be looking for one byte or 2 bytes encodings.

This is where [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) comes to rescue:

```
import chardet

s = r'\xed\xe5 \xff?xb\xff\xe5\xf2\xf1\xff \xef\xf0\xe8\xeb\xee\xe6\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5\xec'

print chardet.detect(s.decode('string_escape'))
# {'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'windows-1251'}
```

If you don't know python, you can also use javascript, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/L3Z4b/

Comment: Thanks! I don't know Python. Do you know if there is any online tool that can help convert messages in the future?

Comment: yes, it's copypaste error. Here is the full error message: `httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 163 of Z:/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load Z:/usr/local/php5/php5apache2_2.dll into server: %1 \xed\xe5 \xff\xe2\xeb\xff\xe5\xf2\xf1\xff \xef\xf0\xe8\xeb\xee\xe6\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5\xec Win32.`

Comment: I've found online Python interpreter - http://repl.it/languages/Python - do you think I can use it to decode messages?

Comment: @Maximus: it doesn't have to be python - you can do the same in any language.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand how. I've tried copying your code to python interpreter but received an error.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`unicode-escape`, `string-escape`  encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
>>> r'\x48\x45\x4C\x4C\x4F'.decode('unicode-escape')
u'HELLO'
>>> r'\x48\x45\x4C\x4C\x4F'.decode('string-escape')
'HELLO'
```